# Where does import code belong in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, import

In my Rails app, I have to import large XML files, that will effect 10 or more models at once.

Now I'm not sure, where the code for this import belongs to. Should I include it in one single model, split it over all the models effected, use modules, or even concerns?

Does anyone have experience with that and can give me some advise?

Answer (score 3):

If the import happens all at once, from one XML file, then just write an import script and put it in `/lib/imports` then call it from a rake task or something. Unless you need to factor it down into class methods I don't see the point, personally.

We import about 600MB of XML every day via several different import scripts and they're all in `/lib/imports` and called from rake tasks which in turn are scheduled and run using cron.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with app/models/tasks/somename_importer.rb and encapsulate all your importer stuff there. You might also create a model for the actual data object you are importing.

```
class ImportedObject
  attr_accessor :have, :some, :accessor, :to, :hold, :data
  def initialize(data, *opts)
    # move data to instance variables
  end

  def to_object
    Object.new(some: mapping)
  end
end

class Tasks::SomeNameImporter
  def initialize
    # maybe setup some logging and stuff
  end

  def perform
    # fetch data from some source via http or file or ftp and iterate over appropriate items
    data.each do |item|
      imported = ObjectToImport.new(item)

      # you can do whatever you want with your imported data
      object   = imported.to_object
      if object.valid?        
        object.save
      else
        # do some logging 
      end
    end    
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you could probably need some methods to interact with xml as well, I would go something like this

```
class XmlBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  #import xml files

  def method_to_parse_xml
      #code
  end
end
```

in your models (which requires xml files)

```
class User < XmlBase

end

class Project < XmlBase

end

#normal models
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Comment: Seems with concerns, or the concept of modules in the lib folder, this proposed scenario wouldn't really be ideal.